# Check dot(.) present in the string without considering it as regular expression

Tags: java, string, methods

I am new to java. I am practicing String methods currently. I wanted to check if the email contains "gmail.com" or not.
This is the code I came up with

```
        System.out.println(domain.matches(".*gmail.com(.*)"));
```

but dot(.) here means any character so even if i pass the string as "xyz@gmailpcom" it will return true. Basically I want to check dot(.) in the string without considering it as regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check whether it contains `gmail.com`, then just use `contains`:

```java
System.out.println(domain.contains("gmail.com"));
```

If at a later stage you want to use a regular expression but escape a dot, do that with a backslash in the regular expression, which needs to be escaped again for use in a Java string literal:

```java
domain.matches(".*gmail\\.com(.*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also check it bu checking the indexOf or lastIndexOf:

```
System.out.println(domain.indexOf("gmail.com") != -1);

System.out.println(domain.lastIndexOf("gmail.com") != -1);
```